# How send list of parameter in Kendo Mvc Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a model which contains a couple of property. These properties are generic list type. On grid read action method i would like to send these parameters as a list to controller. Unfortunately, grid send parameters with zero items. What is the solution for this situation ?

```
  transport.Read("MyAction", "MyController", new { StartDate = Model.StartDate, EndDate = Model.EndDate, RegionsIds= Model.RegionsIds,CityIds = Model.CityIds});
```

Comment: Show us the controller method

Comment: Parameter names and types need to match. Show the relevant code.

Comment: Did you check that the request sent to the controller really contains the expected values? You can get this information from the network console in your browser. It shows all the details of every request.